# fcgio.cpp:50: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, makefile, g++, fastcgi

I am attempting to build fastcgi on a Linux Ubuntu 10.x machine.

I run the following commands:

./configure
make

and I get the following error:

```
fcgio.cpp: In destructor 'virtual fcgi_streambuf::~fcgi_streambuf()':
fcgio.cpp:50: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::overflow(int)':
fcgio.cpp:70: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
fcgio.cpp:75: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::sync()':
fcgio.cpp:86: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
fcgio.cpp:87: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::underflow()':
fcgio.cpp:107: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [fcgio.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/somepath/fcgi-2.4.0/libfcgi'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/somepath/fcgi-2.4.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I notice that others have had the same problem and have asked this question in various fora etc - however, I have not as yet, seen an answer to this question/problem.

Has anyone ever managed to build fastcgi on Linux?
How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

EOF is a C macro and seems that you do not have it defined in fcgio.cpp or that something has undefined it. I would first try to add `#include <stdio.h>` to start of fcgio.cpp.

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported as a bug? It seems hard to get more basic than forgetting to include stdio...

Comment: Check the licenses on the headers. Some of the files we are not even allowed to use because they are "secret to OpenMarket or Copyright 2001 the Tux Linux Pengiun".

Comment: How bout sending them an email on this? : The problem was, i could not find one (i may be wrong)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 11.10 Linux 64bit. Following most of @paercebal's advice I created the following patch which resolved the problem:

```
--- include/fcgio.h 2012-01-23 15:23:51.136063795 +0000
+++ include/fcgio.h 2012-01-23 15:22:19.057221383 +0000
@@ -31,6 +31,7 @@
 #define FCGIO_H

 #include <iostream>
+#include <stdio.h>

 #include "fcgiapp.h"
```