# error while installing sequitor g2p converter

Tags: python

I want to install sequitor g2p a data-driven grapheme-to-phoneme converter

getting error while building sequitor-g2p

I gave command `$ python setup.py install --prefix /usr/local/`

getting error as follows:

```
Utility.cc:43:21: error: ‘EOF’ was not declared in this scope
     if (is.get() == EOF) return EOF;
                     ^
Utility.cc:48:35: error: ‘EOF’ was not declared in this scope
     while (((token = is.get()) != EOF) &&
                                   ^
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See also [fcgio.cpp:50: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577453/fcgio-cpp50-error-eof-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

The easiest option is to add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

to Utility.cc.

You can automatically do this for example using `patch` as in the provided link or by using `sed`:

```
wget http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/web/Software/g2p-r1668.tar.gz
tar xvf  g2p-r1668.tar.gz
rm -r g2p-r1668.tar.gz
cd g2p

sed -i "27 a #include <stdio.h>" Utility.cc 
python setup.py install --prefix  /usr/local
```